# "404 Component not found" when trying to set an image for a category

Tags: joomla-3.x, component, articles, category, images

I'm experiencing a really weird error in the backend of my site - Whenever I try to set an image for a category or article, the modal that pops up just shows me the Joomla dashboard.

[image: Category edit page with "options" selected, before error]

When I'm editing the options of the article or category and click "select" to choose an image, the modal pops up but doesn't show the media files. Instead it just tells me "404 component not found" in the Joomla dashboard. I can browse around through the backend of my website inside the modal that's supposed to be showing me the media files.

[image: Category edit page showing the modal which should contain the media files, and instead contains the 404 component not found error.]

I've updated all of my extensions and even re-installed Joomla, and nothing is helping. I'm using YooTheme Pro, if it helps.

Comment: Welcome to JSE, DShaw.  Please take our [tour] while you wait for support/feedback.